# how to change configuration of maven war plugin from plugin management?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, war

I am trying to figure out how to configure maven war plugin from parent poms plugin management.
Below are two sample poms. This way the war of child project is created with the version attached to the end of the war name although i was trying to create the war only with the artifactId.

If i copy the configuration element to the child pom then the war is created with only the artifactId as expected.

So, what am i missing here ? I thought that plugin management part was just for this kind of stuff ?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>deneme</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>child</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>child Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>deneme</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Is your parent and child part of a multi module build?

Comment: Have you checked via help:effective-pom ?

Comment: my actual projects are just like the samples, a parent po, with some common dependencies and plugins and multiple child projects.

Comment: i am using eclipse and the effective pom looks exactly the same for the child project, weather the configuration part is in the parent pom or in the child pom. And i can clearly see that the warName tag is like <warName>child</warName>, without the version.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the name of final `war` file being created by maven, you need to use `finalName` tag in `build` like.

```
<build>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    ....
</build>
```

[Check this maven reference page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

Comment: The finalname will change only the name which is created into the target folder but not which is going into the maven repository.

Comment: then again, if i use the finalName in parent it has no effect on child war name, if i copy it to the child pom then war name changes...